# how to fill list menu to full screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I developed an Android(version 2.1) app, which contain a List View Menu. This menu filled only half screen only.

Please help me how to fill the List Menu to full screen.

Comment: Do you have the `height` of the `ListView` set to `match_parent`?

Comment: ya, list have the height to match_parent but still I have the same problem.

Comment: Could you show us your XML?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set android:layout_width and android:layout_height to fill_parent?

Comment: ya, I tried it but still same problem. this is my code '
  RelativeLayout containerRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  containerRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  containerRelativeLayout.addView(listView,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
'

Comment: Are you sure the parent `View` that you're trying to fill stretches the entire screen height?

Comment: ya I am sure parent view is filling entire screen. For this issue my menu is showing very small and half of the screen is empty...